# How can I close all chromium tabs Automatically once a day before reboot Pi?

Tags: chromium

When Domoticz and Grafana are open in Chromium on Raspberry Pi 3 b, it uses a lot of memory. That's why I want to close all chromium tabs automatically once a day. I can find a lot about the automatic startup of chromium, tab Domoticz and tab Grafana after a reboot but almost nothing about automatic shutdown.
In ../etc/crontab I already tried to execute 0 5 * * * killall chromium browser. But that doesn't seem to work. Who knows the answer to this question.

This is what I get when tab "Domoticz" and tab "Grafana" are open in chromium:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ps -A | grep -i chrom
 9665 ?        00:00:26 chromium-browse
 9706 ?        00:00:00 chromium-browse
 9708 ?        00:00:00 chromium-browse
 9740 ?        00:00:01 chromium-browse
 9794 ?        00:00:07 chromium-browse
 9799 ?        00:00:37 chromium-browse
 9867 ?        00:00:04 chromium-browse
10103 ?        00:00:00 chromium-browse
```

I tried this:

```
    enter # /etc/crontab: system-wide crontab
# Unlike any other crontab you don't have to run the `crontab'
# command to install the new version when you edit this file
# and files in /etc/cron.d. These files also have username fields,
# that none of the other crontabs do.

SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin

# m h dom mon dow user  command
17 *    * * *   root    cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly
25 6    * * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --repo$
47 6    * * 7   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --repo$
52 6    1 * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --repo$
0 18    50 * *   pi      sudo killall chromium-browser-v7
#0  5    * * *   root    reboot
#0 17    * * *   root    reboot
```

I also tried user root

Comment: "chromium browser" is probably not the name of the process.  Have a look at `ps -A | grep -i chrom` (notice, `chrom` not `chrome`).

Comment: Your comment is unreadable. Please edit your question and add the output to it.

Comment: Just tried that and it doesn't do the job.

Comment: Add the output to your question and format it as a code block (use the `{}` button

Comment: Ahhhh, Done. See below the question above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not that hard to kill a program. You need the **PID** for it or the **correct name**.

For Chromium this would be `chromium-browser` I guess, so run `killall chromium-browser`.

You should also note that there is auto completion in bash. So if you type in `killall chr` and then hit the <kbd>⇥ TAB</kbd> it will complete the right name if it's not ambiguous. Otherwise you could hit it twice to see the possibilities.

Comment: sudo killall chromium-browser-v7 did the trick. Thanks all.

Comment: Unfortunately ~ S it works in the command line but not in the crontab.

Comment: @Copitano for me it works. Are you sure you configured your crontab right? You should add that to your question otherwise nobody could help you with it.

Comment: At 20:00 it worked with user pi.